# Can't use data from redux-form inside my component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-props

I have a simple redux-form on the first page of my project and a button to the next page where I want to display the data from the form.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class UsersList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.form.contact.values)
        // this displays the data
    }

    render(){
        let { firstName, lastName } = this.props.form.contact.values;
        // this doesn't display the data
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{firstName}</p>
                <p>{lastName}</p>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        form: state.form
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UsersList);
```

This is the component where I'm trying to display the data submitted through the form. As you can see in the comments, when I do "console.log(this.props.form.contact.values)" in the componentDidMount method, it works just fine, and I can see the info in the log, but when I try to use it to actually display stuff in the p tags, I get "Cannot read property 'values' of undefined" error.

I don't know it this is relevant, but when console.logging, I get the data in an object. I also tried to map over it inside the return, still without success.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal because when you change route, the `@@redux-form/DESTROY` action will be called emptying all the data from your form and apparently from your `form` reducer, so this

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        form: state.form
    };
};
```

will result to undefined. If you need to persist the form values, you need to tell your form not to destroy itself in unmount.

```
reduxForm({
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(...)
```

Comment: Oh I understand. This was the first time I've heard about this, so thank you, I wouldn't have been able to figure it out by myself.